# How to generate a pulse timer in QNX

Tags: c, timer, real-time, qnx

I'm using QNX to generate a frequently event. The frequence of the event need to be adjusted from time to time by a control loop. I tried to use usleep.

```
while(1)
{
   //performe event
   //calculate phase shift
   usleep(FREQUENCE - drift); // Frequnce is in the range of 1-4 ms
}
```

This works but it produces large jitter of the frequency. I assume this is because usleep blocking the CPU from performing other tasks. QNX is a operating system therefore some other task need to be perfomrmed as well.

So what I would like to do is to use timer instead. As far as i figured out timer allow the perfomens of other processes while my proccess is sleeping.

Sadly I'm new to QNX so I have no idea how to use timer. I only found links to examples generating a frequent timer signal but not adjusting the frequency afterwards.
Thx for your help

PS: I assume a pulse timer is correct because its the timer that is used if you want to wait according to [QNX timer docu](http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/6.4.1/neutrino/getting_started/s1_timer.html?lang=de)

Comment: What interval is 'FREQUENCE'?  Roughly, on average.  Is it in the order of seconds, ms or us?

Comment: @Martin James Between 4 and 1 ms. I would like to use 1 ms but with the usleep the jitter is to high for 1 ms. The system tick time of QNX is 100us.

Comment: Yeah... how much jitter can you tolerate?  If it's of the same order as the OS timer interval then sure, you have a problem.  I suspect that you would need a dedicated hardware timer, together with its interrupt and driver, to handle that.  I'm guessing that you have already raised the priority of your FREQUENCE thread to max?

Comment: Note: Sleep() cals, in general, do not prevent the execution of code in other threads/processes, (they explicitly allow it by freeing up a core!).

Comment: @MartinJames The frequency is only adjusted seldom. The allowed jittter is 250us. I'm using the controle loop to adjust the drift between to uController. This means that the frequency drift is slow but I need to adjust it from time to time. Since you say that usleeps allows the OS to execute other tasks. Do you think that the timer is better than usleep? Process is at maximum priority. PS: Thx for your response

Comment: use the API calls in QNX to access a hardware timer. Set the interrupt for that timer to contain: 1) set the timer interval from a global variable.  2) perform the timed event 3) reset the 'interrupt pending' flag and return.    The global variable is so the rest of the application can adjust the timer interval.  Note: with the system tick time at 100usec, the best accuracy of the timer will be+/- 100usec